# Full class coverage Unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, branch

I'm currently looking into unit testing but not quite sure how full branch and class coverage can be achieved.

Given the following class:

```
public class foo
{

  public int multiply(int a, int b)
  {
      int returnVal = 0;
      if(a==0 || b == 0)
      {
         return returnVal;
      }
      if(a==1)
      {
        return b;
      }
      else if(b==1)
      {
         return a;
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
      {
         returnVal += b;
      }
}
```

What could I do to the above code to make it 100% branch coverage capable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could I do to the above code to make it 100% branch coverage capable?

If I've read your code correctly, then you don't need to change it.  If you want 100% coverage, you just need to design the **test cases** appropriately.

(Hint: if I've counted correctly, you can get 100% coverage with a set of 5 test cases ...)

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. I wanted to be absolutely sure which is why I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cover all your code with 5 unit tests.

### Tests

#### when a = 0

`multiply(0, 13)` must return `0`

#### when b = 0

`multiply(13, 0)` must return `0`

#### when a = 1

`multiply(1, 13)` must return `13`

#### when b = 1

`multiply(13, 1)` must return `13`

#### nominal case

`multiply(5, 4)` must return `20`

### Tip

Note that with Junit you can use [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests).

Answer (score 0):

There are more to add as *coverage criteria* and not only

> full branch and class coverage

will be enough. If we're talking about *Basic coverage criteria* there are a number of coverage criteria, the main ones:

- Function coverage - Has each function (or subroutine) in the program been called?
- Statement coverage - Has each statement in the program been executed?
- *Already mentioned* Branch coverage - Has each branch (aka DD-path) of each control structure (such as in if and case statements) been executed? *For example*, given an if statement, have both the true and false branches been executed? Another way of saying this is, has every edge in the program been executed?
- Condition coverage (or predicate coverage) - Has each Boolean sub-expression evaluated both to true and false?

If you're interested and want to read more about - [code coverage criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage).